# Change tty/pts ssh session between Unix client & server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, administrator, redhat-enterprise-linux

Hello everybody i ask if is possible switch between /dev/pts/1 and dev/tty/1.
I work in env where the connection is bad.
If loss ssh connection i need to restore ssh's session in the same state that when the connexion loss.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the [`mosh`](https://mosh.org/) command - it runs ssh in a persistent session so if you get disconnected you can reconnect exactly where you were before. It's great for using ssh over dodgy cellular data or from trains or cruise ships.

Another choice would be to use a session manager command like `tmux` or `screen` that would also hold persistent sessions for you. But `mosh` is much simpler and doesn't require any special keyboard shortcuts.